# Can I create arbitrary custom calendar colours in Thunderbird/Lighting?

Tags: thunderbird, colors, calendar, lightning

In Thunderbird/Lightning you select from a limited range of custom colours by right-clicking on the calendar and selecting Properties.

[image: custom colours]

However, is it possible to make a calendar an arbitrary colour by specifying #RRGGBB? I have ten calendars, and have devised a colour scheme using [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/?type=qualitative&scheme=Pastel1&n=9) that I wish to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Preferences → Advanced → General → Config Editor...,
input `calendar.registry.*.color` to the search text box and you'll find the settings you want to edit.

To tell which one is for which calendar, search for `calendar.registry.*.name`.

Comment: Excellent find! Thanks. FWIW Thunderbird needs to be restarted before effects are seen.